# Server redirected too many times (20)

Tags: redirect, cookies

I get this error when I try to read a XML from a URL:
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20).

I found a solution, setting the cookies with the following line:
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new ListCookieHandler());
Where the "ListCookieHandler" is a class that I define with configurations from my request.

But this doesn't work. In the javadoc from the method "CookieHandler.setDefault" I found:
"Note: non-standard http protocol handlers may ignore this setting".
I think this could be the problem. There another solution for me?

My code is:

```
int timeout = 120000;
CookieHandler.setDefault(new ListCookieHandler());
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://...").openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
builder.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(builder.toString()));
```

The complete solution for the ListCookieHandler is in the link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/UsingCookieHandlerinJava5.htm

Comment: More context and maybe some sample code where you're getting that exception would go a long way as far as being able to help.

Comment: Ok Jon Lin. I edit my post with my code.

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with your cookie handler and not the URL itslef? When you go to this URL, does it redirect?

Comment: I not so sure. Yes, it redirects. But I tried with the normal URL and redirected URL, and none works.

Answer (score 1):

When I was facing the same error I used:

```
import java.net.CookieHandler;

import java.net.CookieManager;

CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this property **before** calling the `openConnection();`

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```